# How to substitute NULL with value in Power BI when joining one to many

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

In my model I have table `AssignedToUser` that don't contain any NULL values. 
Table `TotalCounts` contains number of tasks for each User.

Those two table joined on UserGUID, and  table TotalCounts contains NULL value for UserGUID.

[image]

When I drop everything in one table there is NULL value for `AssignedToUser`.
How can I substitute value NULL for AssignedToUser for "POOL".

[image]

Under EditQuery I tried to Create additional column

```
if [AssignedToUser] = null then "POOL" else [AssignedToUser]
```

But that didnt help.

UPDATE:
Thanks Alexis.
I have created FullAssignedToUsers table, but when I try to make a relationship with TotalCounts on UserGUID - it doesnt like it.

[image]

Data in new a table looks like this:

[image]

UPDATE:
File .ipbx can be accessed  here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/95frggpaq6tce7q/User%20Open%20Closed%20Tasks%20Experiment.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Not sure why the `UserGUID` values aren't unique, but I recommend the last approach I've edited in below anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that your join has `UserGUID` values that are not in your `AssignedToUsers` table.

To correct this, one possibility is to replace your `AssignedToUsers` table with one that contains all the `UserGUID` values from the `TotalCounts` table.

```
FullAssignedToUsers =
    ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(TotalCounts[UserGUID]),
        "AssignedToUser",
        LOOKUPVALUE(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser],
            AssignedToUsers[UserGUID], TotalCounts[UserGUID]))
```

The should get you the full outer join. You can then create the custom column like you described in the table and use that column in your visual.

You'll probably want to break the relationships with the original `AssignedToUsers` table and create relationships with the new one instead.

If you don't want to take that extra step, you can do an `ISBLANK` inside your new table formula.

```
FullAssignedToUsers =
    ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(TotalCounts[UserGUID]),
        "AssignedToUser",
        IF(
            ISBLANK(
                LOOKUPVALUE(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser],
                    AssignedToUsers[UserGUID], TotalCounts[UserGUID])),
            "POOL",
            LOOKUPVALUE(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser],
                AssignedToUsers[UserGUID], TotalCounts[UserGUID])))
```

---

Note: This is equivalent to doing a right outer join merge on the `AssignedToUsers` table in the query editor and then replacing the nulls with "POOL". I'd actually recommend approaching it that way instead.

---

Another way to approach it is to pull the `AssignedToUser` column over to the `TotalCounts` table in a custom column and use that column in your visual instead.

```
AssignedToUsers =
    IF(ISBLANK(RELATED(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser])),
       "POOL",
       RELATED(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser]))
```

This is equivalent to doing a left outer join merge on the `TotalCounts` table in the query editor, expanding the `AssignedToUser` column, then replacing nulls with "POOL" in that column.

Comment: As I understand correctly `Table3[Name]` would be `AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser]`  ?

Comment: @Oleg Yes. I've edited. I pasted from the file I was testing on and forgot to change the labels.

Comment: Thanks. I created column `TotalCounts [AssignedToUsers]` but when I drop it to Axis it tells me "Cannot determine relationship". I cant believe such simple change can cause so much trouble :).
  Well, I shared the board, but in case of something, I can convince management to imagine "POOL" instead of Blank value.

Comment: @Oleg I looked at your pbix file and the one giving you trouble is related to another table `CountByType`. If you change the relationship between `AssignedToUsers` and `TotalCounts` to be bidirectional filtering, then your visual should work. As it was, there was no path from `TotalCounts` to `CountByType`.

Comment: @AlexisOlson What would be the full join to get a dictionary which has all distinct values of both tables?

Answer (score 2):

In Dax missing values are Blank() not null.  Try this:

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK(AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser]),
    "Pool",
    AssignedToUsers[AssignedToUser]
)
```

Comment: `null` syntax you use when you construct columns in `Edit Query` mode.  I did try to create column the way you suggested, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.  Thanks though

Comment: This column is calculated in modeling window.  Click the new column button on the modeling tab.  This code does not work in the Edit Query mode.

Comment: Yes. `ISBLANK` I used in modeling window.` null` I used in Query Editor window. Both didnt work.

Comment: Try this in the Edit query window. right click on the column with the empty value.  select replace value.... leave the value to find box blank, then put Pool in the Replace with box.